# Azure COSMOS DB how to query for contains in an array

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I make a query to get documents where something contains in the documents array "roles"? I want to get the below document where Trainer is a element in the array.

> ```
> "enabled": true,
> "profilePicture": null,
> "roles": [
>    "Trainer",
>    "Client"
>  ],
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM u WHERE u['$type'] = 'User' AND //roles contains Trainer
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `ARRAY_CONTAINS`. Modifying the query you had:

```
SELECT *
FROM u
WHERE u['$type'] = 'User'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(u.roles, 'Trainer')
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_array_contains).