# cosmos sql query to match array form array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have cosmos db document structure as

```
{
        "studentId": "lkjsdvoijwvsd",
        "studentFirstName": "FirstName",
        "studentLastName": "lastanme",
        "email": "abc.xyz@example.com",
        "phone": "(111) 444-5555",
        "registeredCourses": [
            "courseId1",
            "courseId2",
            "courseId3",
            "courseId4"
        ]
}
```

I have been provided with an input array : `["courseId2","courseId5"]`.
I need to fetch all of the documents which have registeredCourses in input array.

For the above input array I need to fetch all the document which has at least one of the element from input array in **registeredCourses**

I am trying  to get result from  :

```sql
select *
from c
where (c.registeredCourses INTERSECT ["courseId1, "courseId5"] is not blank )
```

Comment: is it possible to do by cosmos sql query ? Please help

Comment: you can use this query to get the desired output `Select * from Student s where ARRAY_CONTAINS(s.registeredCourses,"courseId2")` you can refer this doc for your reference 
https://novacontext.com/writing-and-running-queries-on-nosql-document-databases/

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried, and the issues you're having. Posting a requirement, followed by "provide the exact sql query" isn't really how this site works. Aside from that, this is a duplicate of other questions asking about array inclusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure COSMOS DB how to query for contains in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662161/azure-cosmos-db-how-to-query-for-contains-in-an-array)

Comment: I am not able to use ARRAY_CONTAINS(argument1, argument2) because in my case agument2 is also array @PratikLad-MT

Comment: I am not able to use ARRAY_CONTAINS(argument1, argument2) because in my case agument2 is also array @DavidMakogon
I am trying  to get result from  : select * from c where (c.registeredCourses INTERSECT ["courseId1, "courseId5"] is not blank )